# Different files for error and debug logs in Spring boot

Tags: logging, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

Setting log file in **logging.file=myapplication.log** in application.properties will print all the logs, However I want two separate log files for **error** and **info**, How can I achieve this.

I have referred this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499443/how-to-write-log-messages-to-file-using-spring-boot)

But could not figure it out

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?